# If $f$ is holomorphic function then are the zeros of $\Re(f)$ isolated?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function.

We know that the the zeros of $f$ are isolated

I would like to know if is it true that the zeros of $\Re(f)$ are isolated.

Thanks.

Comment: By taking $f(z)=z^2$, $f$ is holomorphic and one sees that $\text{Re}f(z)=x^2-y^2$ admits the lines $y=x$, $y=-x$ as zeros. This is explained by @Adayah's answer.

Comment: thanks @OlivierOloa for this counterexamples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: consider $f(z) = z$ and the set $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : \Re(z) = 0 \}$.

In fact, zeros of $\Re(f)$ are rarely isolated, because if $f(x+iy) = u(x, y) + i v(x, y)$ is holomorphic (where $u$ and $v$ are real), then under some natural assumption* the solution to the equation $u(x, y) = 0$ is a one-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}$, which is clearly not a discrete set.

*When $0$ is a [regular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem) of $u(x, y)$ and $0 \in \operatorname{im} u$.

Comment: ok @Adayah thanks for your answer, i understood that it's not true

Comment: @Adayah Nice answer. (+1)